# The procedure to get Ubuntu running on different hardware besides RPI

Tags: embedded-system

extremely new here!

Over the long weekend I finally caved in and grabbed myself a [STM32MP157F-DK2](https://www.st.com/resource/en/data_brief/stm32mp157f-dk2.pdf). It booted up to what I think is a tutorial linux-esque OS to show you around the hardware and capabilities of the device, and I was amazed.

Knowing this Linux-OS was most likely limited I wanted something big, so I tried getting Ubuntu onto this device to further play around with everything. Went onto [Ubuntu Supported platforms](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/supported-platforms) and downloaded the "Ubuntu-core-22-pi" as its the same MPU as the STM32MP157F. It was a image file so I just flashed it onto the little microSD card that came with the STM32 device and inserted it back in once it was done, and nothing happened!

I am not too surprised this didn't work as I am new to the embedded linux field, but this had led me to a series of questions that I am hoping I can find the answers here.

1. Why did the flashing onto the SD card not work? From searching it seems like having the .img file is the simplest way to get linux onto an embedded device as mentioned here [@7:59](https://youtu.be/9vsu67uMcko?t=479). They are both ARM Cortex - A7 with the caveat that the RPI2 is a quad core and the STM32MP157 is a dual core.
2. I believe I understand that vendors have their own linux distribution to use but what would happen when someone creates a custom board, how is it typically done to get a linux distrubtion onto a board.
3. At the end of the day I would love to learn how one gets a linux distrubtion onto the STM32MP157F (Preferably Ubuntu) as I want to learn and make my own Kernel drivers.

As I mentioned I do apologize in advance for this lack luster questions. I am new to all this as I come from a background of MCUs and want to expand my horizons so to speak.

Have a great day and thank you for reading. Looking forward to all messages,
Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! General rule is that images for pi works only on pi. STM32MP157F is not supported by Canonical.

Comment: @pasmanpasmański Thank you for the welcome! I see, question, even if I have a Quad-Core Cortex - A7 would I still be able to use the PI image or no? And if not how would one even get Ubuntu on another embedded device besides a PI

Comment: No. Pi image starts a firmware blob at begin. This firmware is secret and specific for pi. Your board need own firmware.

Comment: @pasmanpasmański Is it then possible to get Ubuntu on this board STM32MP157 at all?